# I Can't open SQL Server Compact 3.5 on Visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-ce

I want to open a sql compact database v3.5 with visual studio 2008.

I have downloaded `ssceRuntime` and Installed it.

Then I followed this approach: `Server Explorer > Connect to a database > Change`

In this small window I haven't the `Sql Server compact 3.5`.

how can I add the required sdk?

Comment: Have you installed VS 2008 SP1?

Comment: No. Is that an update?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13276

Comment: I'm downloading this package.Thank you for answering and for the link. :)

Comment: Let me know if that fixes your issue, and I will make it an answer, please

Comment: This update was too big in comparison to it's benefits.Just two files of this package was needed:
SSCERuntime-enu.msi and SSCEVSTools-ENU.msi
But at least my problem was solved,so thank you ErikEJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install the SQL Compact Tooling support installer, which is included with VS 2008 SP 1, specifically Sscevstools-enu.msi